# Angular 16.2.12 ComponentPortal no longer extends Portal<any>

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to render components dynamically using `cdkPortalOutlet` but seems like the `ComponentPortal` no longer extends `Portal<any>`.

**TS**

```
private injector = inject(Injector);

public stepPortal = new ComponentPortal(ServiceSetupStepComponent, this.injector);
```

**HTML**

```
<ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="stepPortal"></ng-template>
```

**Error**

Type 'ComponentPortal' is not assignable to type '"" | Portal | null | undefined'.
Type 'ComponentPortal' is not assignable to type 'Portal'.
Types have separate declarations of a private property '_attachedHost'.

**portal.d.ts**

```
export declare class ComponentPortal<T> {...}
```

Funny thing is that `TemplatePortal` extends `Portal`

**index.d.ts**

```
export declare class TemplatePortal<C = any> extends Portal<EmbeddedViewRef<C>> {
```

Answer (score 0):

As usually I found the solution in 5 minutes after I published the question, keeping in account the 2 hours of research before publishing the question. I have imported a wrong `ComponentPortal` from `ngx-toastr` instead of importing it from `@angular/cdk/portal`